# maven EAR plugin configuration

Tags: maven, ear

i have problem with ear plugin configuration, exactly i want to place one of jar dependency in root directory in ear and rest of them in lib directory. Can someone help me with this?

Update:

I have 4 projects, one of them is a container, pom type. One of them is a ear with two dependencies, war and jar. I want to create ear with directory structure:

/ - a.war and b.jar projects
/lib/ - all dependencies for 'a' and 'b' projects
/META-INF/ - MANIFEST.MF

part of pom.xml

```
            <configuration>
                <!-- <artifactTypeMappings>
                    <artifactTypeMapping type="war" mapping="webModule" />
                </artifactTypeMappings> -->
                <webModule>
                    <groupId>a</groupId>
                    <artifactId>a</artifactId>
                    <contextRoot>/a</contextRoot>
                    <bundleFileName>a.war</bundleFileName>
                    <bundleDir>lib</bundleDir>
                </webModule>
                <jarModule>
                    <groupId>b</groupId>
                    <artifactId>b</artifactId>
                    <bundleDir>/</bundleDir>
                    <bundleFileName>/b.jar</bundleFileName>
                </jarModule>
                <defaultLibBundleDir>lib</defaultLibBundleDir>
            </configuration>
```

Comment: Can you post your pom.xml file. Hard to guess ...

Comment: thanks for comment, I have updated post, i hope that now is more clear

Answer (score 0):

A simple look into the [documentation would have helped](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-ear-plugin/modules.html#jarModule). You just remove the bundleDir entry from the entry you like to place into root location.

```
<jarModule>
 <groupId>b</groupId>
 <artifactId>b</artifactId>
 <bundleFileName>/b.jar</bundleFileName>
</jarModule>
```

Comment: ok, i have manage with this issue, i didn't add tag <modules>